# Input a set of numbers and output the Largest, smallest and average

Tags: loops, for-loop, if-statement, vbscript

I'm using VBscript.

So as the title says I need to input a set of number and I must output the largest of them, the smallest and the average.

I have no idea how to do the Average, however I did the largest and the smallest but came up with an error ("Out of stack space" "Largest" Line 6)

(Sorry about the format not sure how to edit it)

```
function Largest(a)
    maxi = -99999
    if a>maxi then
    maxi=a
end if
msgbox Largest(a)
end function

function Smallest(a)
    maxi = +99999
    if a<maxi then
    maxi=a
end if
msgbox Smallest(a)
end function



n = inputbox("Enter the numbers of items")
for i = 1 to n
a = CInt(InputBox("Enter Item " &i))
Largest(a)
Smallest(a)
next
```

I figured how to calculate the average, but don't know how to incorporate it in the code above:

```
n=inputbox("Enter number of items")
sum = 0
for i = 1 to n
a = inputbox("enter items "&i)
sum = sum + a
next
avg = sum/n
msgbox avg
```

Comment: `I'm using VBscript` then you used the wrong tag.  VB.NET is to VBScript as Car is to Carpet.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I have never done any vb script but finding the average is as simple as summing all the elements and dividing by the count of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Use WScript.Arguments instead of InputBox and just one Function to compute the values. As in:

```
Option Explicit

' returns average, minimum, and maximum of the non-empty 
' array a containing only numbers 
Function avmima(a)
  If "Variant()" <> TypeName(a) Then Err.Raise 4711, "needs array", "avmima"
  If -1 = UBound(a)             Then Err.Raise 4712, "needs non-empty array", "avmima" 
  If Not IsNumeric(a(0))        Then Err.Raise 4713, "needs array of numbers", "avmima" 
  Dim t : t = Array(a(0), a(0), a(0))
  Dim i
  For i = 1 To UBound(a)
      If Not IsNumeric(a(i)) Then Err.Raise 4714, "needs array of numbers", "avmima" 
      t(0) = t(0) + a(i)
      If t(1) > a(i) Then t(1) = a(i)
      If t(2) < a(i) Then t(2) = a(i)
  Next
  t(0) = t(0) / i 
  avmima = t 
End Function

Dim a : a = Array(1, 2, 3)
If 0 < WScript.Arguments.Unnamed.Length Then
   ReDim a(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed.Length - 1)
   Dim i    
   For i = 0 To UBound(a)
       a(i) = CDbl(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(i))
   Next
End If 
WScript.Echo Join(a, vbTab) 
WScript.Echo Join(avmima(a), vbTab)
WScript.Echo Replace("Av Mi Ma", " ", vbTab)

'a = avmima("")
'a = avmima(Array())
'a = avmima(Split("1 Zwei 3"))
```

output:

```
cscript avmima.vbs
1       2       3
2       1       3
Av      Mi      Ma

cscript avmima.vbs 0 0 0
0       0       0
0       0       0
Av      Mi      Ma

cscript avmima.vbs -1 -2 -3
-1      -2      -3
-2      -3      -1
Av      Mi      Ma

cscript avmima.vbs 1,5 2,5 5,0 (german locale!)
1,5     2,5     5
3       1,5     5
Av      Mi      Ma
```

Comment: Thanks for taking to time to write this, but problem is my knowledge in Vbscript as our instructor taught us doesn't go beyond conditions statement, functions and the "For" loop and I need to write the code using only what he taught us which mean no arrays or WScript.Arguments . Is this even possible at all to begin with?

Comment: @Dan better get on with it then.